# Error Message 'class::function' : illegal call of non-static member function

Tags: c++

i was trying to call a static function of class using scope resolution operator, the way to access static function but still generating error. what are the possibilities.

Comment: Make sure it's static. The error message indicates otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

The error message says it all: you are calling a **non-static member function** thinking it as static.

Answer (score 0):

The obvious possibility is that your function is *not static*, as the error message clearly says. There are no meaningful way to guess at any other possibilities with the information you provided.